# Dynamic Pivot on incremental Value in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I am facing issue in SQL Server logic.

Below is my data set:

```
NPI         Name
1669444980  ABC
1669444980  DEF
1669444980  GHI
1669444980  ABC
1669444980  IJK
1669444980  DEF
```

I am looking to get the data in the below format where column name automatic incremented as per distinct value in Name column.
Name1, Name2 goes as long distinct value in Name column to make a single line on NPI basis.

```
NPI         Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4 
1669444980  ABC     DEF     GHI     IJK
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query-:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',''' + [NAME_COLUMN] +''' as Name'+ cast((rank() over (order by [NAME_COLUMN])) as varchar(100))
    from [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
    group by [NAME_COLUMN]
FOR XML PATH(''), Type
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT distinct NPI_COLUMN, ' + @cols + N' from [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```